# Hardy Littlewood Circle Method

Tags: integration, number-theory, gamma-function

I'm working through Vaughan's book on the Hardy Littlewood circle method, which uses the following lemma:

Suppose that $\alpha \geq \beta$ are positive real numbers, and that $\beta \leq 1$. Then:

$ \sum \limits_{m=1}^{n-1} m^{\beta-1}(n-m)^{\alpha-1} = n^{\beta+\alpha-1} (\frac{ \Gamma(\beta) \Gamma(\alpha) }{ \Gamma(\beta+\alpha) } + O(n^{-\beta})
$

For the proof they define the function $\phi(\gamma) = \gamma^{\beta-1}(n-\gamma)^{\alpha-1}$ and proceed as follows:

On $(0,n)$ it has at most one stationary point, so we can divide it into two intervals $(0,X),(X,n)$, one of which may be empty, such that $\phi$ is increasing on one and decreasing on the other. Therefore 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \phi(m) & = \int_0^{n} \phi(\gamma)d\gamma + O(n^{\alpha-1}) \\
      & = \frac{ \Gamma(\beta) \Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta+\alpha)} + O(n^{\alpha-1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

How does the gamma function appear? I tried evaluating the integral of $\phi$ via integration by parts but I don't see the gamma function popping up.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Beta Function wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: First or second edition?

Comment: 2nd, i'm finding it quite terse